# Reloading keys in AVAsset when status is AVKeyValueStatusFailed

Tags: ios, avfoundation, avasset

I'm doing the following:

- Create a new `AVAsset` with a given URL. That URL points to a video on a remote web server.
- Attempt to load the `tracks` property by calling `loadValuesAsynchronouslyForKeys:completionHandler:`
- The initial request fails, because no internet connection exists
- I notice that the request failed by calling `statusOfValueForKey:error:`
- I then wait for the connection to re-appear (using some reachability code). As soon as it does, I call `loadValuesAsynchronouslyForKeys:completionHandler:` again.

Here's where the problems begin. I would imagine that the `AVAsset` goes ahead and attempts to reload the tracks property since it failed previously. However, this does not seem to happen. `statusOfValueForKey:error:` will still return `AVKeyValueStatusFailed`, although a working internet connection is available and the video is playable.

Is there a way to reset the state for this given property and to attempt another load? Is there another way to work around this?

Comment: Just a possibility, did you tried doing `cancelLoading` after it fails?

Comment: Are you checking each of the keys? The keys each have their own status and come up randomly (not really, but that is how it will feel timing wise) and not all at the same time. The first rule of video streaming is it's really stranger than it looks at first

Answer (score 2):

1. Are you creating a new AVURLAsset or just reusing the previous one?
2. In the completion handler for `loadValuesAsynchronouslyForKeys:completionHandler:` are you dispatching back to the main thread?

What happens if you call this method again (or something similar) when you're ready to retry.

```
- (void)setContentURL:(NSURL *)contentURL
{
    if (_contentURL != contentURL) {
        _contentURL = contentURL;

        AVURLAsset *asset = [AVURLAsset URLAssetWithURL:_contentURL options:nil];

        NSArray *requestedKeys = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:ISIVideoPlayerControllerTracksKey, ISIVideoPlayerControllerPlayableKey, nil];

        [asset loadValuesAsynchronouslyForKeys:requestedKeys completionHandler: ^{
             dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                 [self prepareToPlayAsset:asset withKeys:requestedKeys];
             });
         }];
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm reusing the same AVURLAsset. I'm dispatching back to the main queue, yes.

Comment: On retry recreate the AVURLAsset, basically start from scratch. I assume that there's some state remaining after the failure. It should be fast to create the asset as long as you're not passing in the AVURLAssetPreferPreciseDurationAndTimingKey option.